# How to do Javascript and jQuery Code Review

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anybody let me know how is Code Review done for the javascript or jQuery Code. What are the points that are to be strictly checked in Code Reviews.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try out http://jshint.com/ and follow this: http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html

Comment: Thanks. It gives me the starting point.